# Creating lock object in main thread causing ANR

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I've an object that's created when the class is instantiated. I create a lock i-e; wait() on that object inside a background thread, however the app still gets unresponsive. My understanding of synchronization/locking is that if object.wait() is called in the main thread than it's equivalent to blocking the main thread however if it's called inside a background thread (even though the object upon which wait() is called in the main thread, shouldn't cause problems).

Can someone please help me out understanding this?

Example code:

```
class MyClass {
   private final Object myLockObject = new Object();

   public void connect() {
      new Thread(new Runnable{
        mSocket.connect();
        myLockObject.wait(); // causing ANR
     }).start();
   }

  private void socketConnectCallback() {
      //upon callback
      myLockObject.notifyAll();
  }
}

class MyAndroidService extends Service {

   public void onStartCommand() {
      MyClass myClassObject = new MyClass();
      myClassObject.connect();
      //it immediately returns here even with the code written above.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this code will throw an `IllegalMonitorStateException`. This is because before calling `object.wait()`, you need to make sure that you are holding the object's monitor. One way to do this is to use:

```
synchronised(object) {
    // this thread now owns the object's monitor
    object.wait();
}
```

Further, the thread that calls for `object.wait()` relinquishes its ownership on that object's monitor and waits for some other thread to notify it. Once it gets the notification, it will wait until it reacquires the object's monitor (since some other thread might be having the ownership of that monitor even if the waiting thread got the notify signal). Then it continues normal execution.

In your case, the background thread should block, and the main thread should continue executing normally. Isn't this what you have mentioned is happening?

Comment: That's not what's happening. It's still blocking the main thread. I don't understand the reason behind it

Comment: Weird. Can you explain what this means "//it immediately returns here even with the code written above."

Comment: connect method in the service immediately returns like an async method

Comment: Man I am not sure how this thing is even working. The new thread doesn't even have the ownership of the object's monitor. This code should throw an IllegalMonitorStateException. By main thread, you mean the thread that calls connect() right?

Comment: why doesn't the new thread have the ownership of the myLockObject monitor? It's calling myLockObject.wait in synchronized(myLockObject) clause

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this will help so much, but I can't comment so I want to get your attention to this code:

```
newThread(new Runnable {
mSocket.connect();
myLockObject.wait();
}).start();
```

This must be like:

```
(new Thread( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            mSocket.connect(); // connect takes argument(s)
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Catch the excpetion
        }
        try {
            myLockObject.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Catch the excpetion
        }
    }
})).start();
```

and since `Runnable` is a functional interface you can use lambda expression instead of creating a new object.
**Edit:**
I think I figured out what do you want to do, if you want to make a thread that connects the socket and then wait to be notified and want it to acquire the intrinsic lock of the object `myLockObject` to prevent interleaving then you have to put the code you want to be executed by the thread in a guarded block:

```
private final void connectSocket() {
    synchronized(myLockObject) {
        try {
            mSocket.connect(null);
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        try {
            myLockObject.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

and in the connect method just call `connectSocket`

```
public void connect() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                connectSocket();
            }
        }).start();
}
```